# Jquery - serialize form fields in DIV's by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, serialization

Is it possible to get form field data and serialize it by using the class assigned to two divs ?

I have 4 divs that contain form fields, only two DIVs are shown at a time.  What is shown depends on a drop down selection.

- if `select = 1`, the divs with the class `classOne` are show and divs with `classTwo` are hidden
- if `select = 2`, the divs with the class `classTwo` are show and divs with `classOne` are hidden

When I submit the form, I want to serialize either both divs with `classOne`, or `classTwo`, depending on what was selected in the dropdown.

So far I can't get it to serialize the form date from the divs..

```
data: $('.classOne').serializeArray(),
```

This doesn't pass any data to my back end script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to target the form controls within those elements. You can use the pseudo selector [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to cover various control tags and types

```
data: $('.classOne :input').serializeArray()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n5yfwhjx/)**</kbd>

Another common way to do this is to use `<fieldset>` tags and disable the inactive ones. Disabling a fieldset disables any form controls within it so you can then effectively use `serialize()` on the whole form since it does not include disabled controls

Comment: Thanks - does setting the fields as `Display:none` disable the input fields  ?

Comment: Thanks - I've used fieldsets and that seems to work well :)

Answer (score 1):

`serializeArray()` return all enabled input field data. You need to disable the input fields which you don't want `serializeArray()` to return.

When you select the dropdown, set the `attribute` of `input` fields to `disabled`.

To make input field disabled :

`$(input).attr('disabled','disabled')`;

if select = 1, the divs with the class 'classOne' are show and divs with 'classTwo' are hidden and `disabled`

if select = 2, the divs with the class 'classTwo' are show and divs with 'classOne' are hidden and `disabled`